# I am trying to make react app but some circular dependency errors are coming

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, nvm, npx

These are the errors.
C:\fcc>npx create-my-app app
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'cat' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'cd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'chmod' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'cp' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'dirs' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'pushd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'popd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'echo' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'tempdir' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'pwd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'exec' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'ls' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'find' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'grep' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'head' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'ln' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'mkdir' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'rm' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'mv' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'sed' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'set' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'sort' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'tail' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'test' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'to' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'toEnd' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'touch' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'uniq' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:2056) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'which' of module exports inside circular dependency

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTI4a.png)

I tried making new folders, reinstalling nvm and node, asking Chatgpt, Google, Youtube. And the problem pertains.

Comment: `npx create-react-app my-app` is the correct syntax. You should now use `vite` instead of cra.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.